# Is it possible to change the domain Url for the Production org?

Tags: url, production

Our project manager bought the enterprise edition of Salesforce for our project with some random domain name(not relevant to theme of the actual project) which looks out-of-context. I would like to change that domain name something more meaningful.

I haven't reached out to him to see if he can do something at his end to change the domain name(as he is the PM, asking this kind of question might give a bad impression) as he made the purchase.

Is this even possible? If yes, do I need to talk to my PM or do I need to open a case at Salesforce Support?

Comment: AFAIK - The only people who could change it (if it can be changed) would be salesforce

Answer (score 1):

No, you cann't. You will need to raise a level 2 case I believe https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_overview.htm&language=en&type=0

Answer (score 1):

See [Can I change or remove my subdomain name?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_domain_name_rename.htm&language=en_US&type=0), copied here for your convenience:

> You can’t change the subdomain name that you create with My Domain.
>   And after your subdomain is deployed, you can’t reverse deployment. If
>   you need to change your subdomain name, contact Salesforce Customer
>   Support.

You and your administrators cannot fix this directly, but may log a case with Support.